# knockout.js - root access viewmodel

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js

Is there a way to access the root viewmodel from inside the callback of an item in a list?

Example:

```
function Employee() {
    var self = this;
    this.notes = ko.observableArray();

    this.addNote = function() {
       // need to access the EmployeeViewModel here in order to set its detailedNote 
    }
}

function EmployeeViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    this.employees= ko.observableArray([]);

    // observables used as placeholders in modal windows
    this.detailedEmployee = ko.observable();
    this.detailedNote = ko.observable();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming at some point you are going to add instances of Employee to the employees observableArray in your view model. When you create your instances pass the parentVM to your Employee constructor. The only caveat is that you won't be able to call ko.toJSON because when it tries to stringify the object it will just keep going around in circles.

I had to make a few inferences because you didn't provide a lot of details but I tried to throw an example together for you.

http://jsfiddle.net/bczengel/trm7y/

On a side note, a little tip when creating multiple instances of objects, put your internal functions into the prototype of the constructor so your not creating copies of functions that do the same thing.  For instance, your addNote function would be created once for every instance of Employee you create. If you use prototypal inheritance only one will be created. This change is also in my example.

Answer (score 0):

there is  $root, which you could pass into your callback,   or you create your employees with knowledge of the VM,  or ugly, have a global ( or repository ),  or don't have the note on the VM, or attach the function to the employee from the view model capturing the "self" of the VM....